# How can I use regex in when condition

Tags: regex, ansible

On an Ansible playbook, I'm trying to execute a shell command only if a service exist on the remote server.

I have 3 tasks :

- service_facts
- execution of shell command if tomcat is installed
- display the output of the shell command if tomcat is installed

Here is my code :

```
- name: Get Infos
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: false
  remote_user: [MY_USER]

  tasks:
  - name: Get the list of services
    service_facts:

  - name: Get version of Tomcat if installed
    become: true
    shell: 'java -cp /opt/tomcat/lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo | grep "Server version"'
    register: tomcat_version
    when: "'tomcat.service' in services"

  - debug: msg="{{ tomcat_version.stdout_lines }}"
    when: "'tomcat.service' in services"
```

The problem is on certains servers the service name is, for example, `tomcat-8.1`

How can i use regex in the when condition?

I tried `regex()`, `regex_search()`, either I'm doing it wrong or I don't know how to do it.

Have you any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count matching items. For example

```yaml
    - service_facts:
    - block:
        - shell: smartctl --version | head -1
          register: smart_version
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ smart_version.stdout_lines }}"
      when: _srvcs|length > 0
      vars:
        _regex: '.*smart.*'
        _srvcs: "{{ services|select('match', _regex) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-73-generic] (local build)
```

---

The next option is to *intersect* the list of services, e.g.

```yaml
      when: _srvcs|length > 0
      vars:
        my_services:
          - smartmontools.service
          - smart-8.1
          - smart-devel.0.0.1
        _srvcs: "{{ my_services|intersect(services) }}"
```

---

**Debug**

Q: ***"It gives me a failure on the server where my service doesn't exist, cause the playbook still tries to execute the shell. Is it normal?"***

A: No. It is not normal. Print debug and find out why the condition evaluates to *true*, i.e. what service(s) match either the regex or the list. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          _srvcs:
            {{ _srvcs|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
      when: debug|d(false)|bool
      vars:
        my_services:
          - smartmontools.service
          - smart-8.1
          - smart-devel.0.0.1
        _srvcs: "{{ my_services|intersect(services) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    _srvcs:
      - smartmontools.service
```

To enable the task run the playbook with the option `-e debug=true`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

With count matching items, it works, but it give me a failed on server where my service doesn't exist, cause the playbook still try to execute the shell. Is it normal?

Comment: You are welcome! Debug the task. I updated the answer. Then [edit] question and add the [mre] details for others to learn what was going wrong.